# Editing of the help center and about

Tags: discussion, moderation

Try to add some meat to the [on topic page](https://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic). Also, in the [about](https://mathoverflow.net/about) page, you can edit the site target audience, the example question, and the bullet points that define what to ask about/what not to ask about.

You may want to create a draft as an answer here and collaboratively work on it; that's how new sites usually do it.

These are all moderator-editable. I suggest you look at the [corresponding](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) [pages](https://math.stackexchange.com/about) on MSE for ideas.

Comment: Especially so given a question like this popping up on the SE Meta: [What's the difference between MathOverflow & Mathematics.SE?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185784/whats-the-difference-between-mathoverflow-mathematics-se)

Comment: About now says "MathOverflow is a question and answer site for professional mathematicians. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about research level mathematics." Isn't the last part a bit ambitious?