# The 6 semi-essential meta questions of every SE 2.0 upgrade

Tags: discussion

> In the spirit of [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)

I realized that there were a few things that needed to be decided by a large site that has suddenly gone SE 2.0. Initially I planned to make meta posts for each one, but then I realized that there were many of them, and since I'm not an active MO user, I wouldn't know which would be necessary. I've listed them here, feel free to use them as starting points for individual meta posts:

- [**Site-specific off topic close reasons**](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/183/21425): [A lot of changes to the close system were rolled out recently.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes) This includes the ability for moderators to add off topic subreasons.  (For example, on Physics, we have a "homework question" subreason.) A meta post asking for possible reasons with the wording would be nice.
- [**Deciding the contents of your <s>FAQ</s> help center**](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/83/editing-of-the-help-center-and-about): I've [already asked](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/83/editing-of-the-help-center-and-about) this one, as it is rather essential. You may *also* want to request an extra help center topic for mathjax (Like [this page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on Physics)
- **Migration paths**: There has already been a thread [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/141/what-outgoing-migration-paths-should-we-have). Looking at it, there are many options and some hard stats on how many of each type of post would be useful. I suggest that you wait for a month (or two), check the migration stats (available to 10k+ users), and make individual meta posts for each migration path you want.
- **Chatroom Etiquette and owners**: It's not yet clear if [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9369/mathoverflow) is going to be used much. I personally suggest that you do try it out -- it's a great place to informally discuss various things, both on and off topic. If you do indeed decide to use it, I suggest you draft out a chatroom etiquette post [like this one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3890/main-chatroom-etiquette-rules). A lot of folks have expressed concerns over chat being flooded by homework; you may want to explicitly make it off topic for chat (and thus homework askers can be easily kicked, and chatbanned if persistent). You may also want to appoint room owners from the regulars so that they can help moderate chat.
- **Request a blog**: (See http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/ and [a list of current blogs](http://stackexchange.com/blogs)) Another cool SE feature is that sites can collaboratively run their own blog. If you feel that there are enough people in the community who will be able to maintain a steady stream of posts, start a meta post about this, asking if the community thinks that it's a good idea and fielding for volunteers. (More details on the process [here)](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/)
- **Request Question/Answer bans**: (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans). When a user posts multiple low-quality (downvoted, closed, or deleted) questions (or answers) they can get question (answer) banned. This means that they cannot continue to ask questions (answers) unless they improve their existing ones or write new answers(questions) which get upvoted. If you get a lot of persistent homework help or other types of bad questions, this may be useful. (Answer bans are rare)

Comment: good. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @WillJagy No abusing mathjax to make short comments :P

Comment: @Man: Ok. ${ }$

Comment: $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$What.

Comment: Got it. $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $  $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @dimension10 see also http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/462/on-using-mathjax-to-create-white-space for discussion an info related to short comments