# Mathematics and MathOverflow relationship

Tags: support, math-stackexchange

Is there a connection between Mathematics and MathOverflow sites? Obviously topics are similar, but I mean something like: do questions posted on one site, perhaps with certain tags, automatically end up on the other one? I have seen in the past same questions posted on both sites at the same time and I was wondering if users did it manually or not.

Also, how do I decide what topics are for overflow and what are for regular site? I know that calculating a basic limit should be on the regular site, but there are some questions that I'm not sure about. Should I post those on both sites?

I hope I'm posting this at the right place 
Thanks in advance

Comment: An older post on this site: [How is this site different from Mathematics Stack Exchange?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/271) See also:  [What's the difference between MathOverflow & Mathematics.SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185784) (Meta Stack Exchange)
and [Differences between mathoverflow and math.stackexchange.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/41) (Meta Mathematics).

Comment: We have been complaining for a while that this difference is not presented clearly enough to new users; see [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3386/should-users-be-shown-some-basic-information-before-posting-the-first-question) for instance. This question is another confirmation that this is a real problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no formal connection. You may often see the same question on both sites because a lot of people cross-post (manually), a practice which is generally frowned upon, **especially** when the same question appears at both sites almost simultaneously and the poster doesn't mention anything about cross-posting or doesn't link to the question at the other site. So no, please don't post on both sites at the same time -- at least give one site a reasonable opportunity to answer your question first.

Unless you feel your question is the type of question that a mathematics PhD student or mathematician might plausibly ask, you are generally better off asking at Mathematics. One trouble though is the sheer volume of questions there. Without having done a careful study, my impression is that the easy calculus-type questions or other low-hanging fruit get readily answered, but harder questions can get buried under the accumulating pile, which can be frustrating. Often I'll see an MO post that starts off "I tried asking at Mathematics but got no response, so I'm asking here instead." People here are often understanding of that situation.

It's generally fine to ask here at meta whether a specific question is suitable for MO.

Comment: I'll just add that the **reason** not to post on both sites is that it can create a situation where people here (or there) are devoting effort to answering your question without realizing that it's already been answered there (or here).

Comment: If you repost a question on another site under any circumstances, **always** include in both questions cross-links to each other.